# How can adapter send other parameters from array with objects to listview?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I must admit that theory of adapters is not completely clear to me. In my app, I created ListView with parking places numbers and want to change a color of text based on their availability. ListView items get numbers from the array with "Dock" Objects, where every DockPlace has ID (number) and isAvailabile Status. My adapter can take numbers from Dock Object and put it in ListView. It also can change text colour, but I don't have any idea how can I get other parameters about objects.

Adapter:

```
ListView docksList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.docksList);
    ArrayAdapter<Dock> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Dock>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            Dock.docks //Dock - class name. docks - name of array with Dock Objects
    ) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            //in this place could be IF statement which check status of dock and can change text color depends on its

            text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

            return view;
        }
    };
```

Dock:

```
public static final Dock[] docks = {
    new Dock(1, true),
    new Dock(2, true),
    new Dock(3, false),
};
private Dock(int number, boolean isAvailable) {
    this.number = number;
    this.isAvailable = isAvailable;
    }
public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}
public boolean getStatus() {
    return isAvailable;
}
public String toString() {
    String numberStr = "Dock no "+ String.valueOf(this.number);
    return numberStr;
}
```

Comment: did you try if else where you commented inside getView() method , it will work if you add it

Comment: boolean availableStatus=listAdapter .get(position).getStatus(); 
check using this, if true set color

Comment: simple ! 
make a loop to iterate the array in order to take the indices, the list view fields positions will be same with your array so 
 listView.get(postion) is equal to docks.get(position)
in this way you can get the full object even if the list is not took with full object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` is just one concrete implementation of the `ListAdapter` interface; there's also `BaseAdapter` and anything you'd like to implement yourself.

`ArrayAdapter` does a pretty good job of hiding all the hard work it's doing, but in this case some of what's being hidden from you is exactly what you need.

When you construct your adapter with this code:

```
ArrayAdapter<Dock> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Dock>(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        Dock.docks //Dock - class name. docks - name of array with Dock Objects
)
```

the important thing to understand is that your adapter is going to hold on to `Dock.docks` as its own private field (named `mObjects`) and that there are ways you can access this field in your own code.

You can add values to the adapter using `add()`, `addAll()`, `insert()`, etc. You can remove objects using `remove()` or `clear()`. And the one that's relevant to you: you can access the object at a given `position` by using `getItem()`.

Since the `position` is available in the `getView()` method, this means you can access the "current" `Dock` object quite easily. Perhaps you could use this code:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

        if (getItem(position).getStatus()) {
            text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        else {
            text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getItem(position) function of ArrayAdapter class for getting instance of dock object at particular position.

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       Dock dock=  getItem(position);   
       // do your stuff
   }
```